# REST API Response format best practise

Tags: rest

So i have a rest API as follows

```
/buildings/{id}
```

which returns the following

```
{
   "id":....
   "name":....
}
```

I also have another endpoint

```
/buildings/{id}/workers
```

which returns all the workers

```
{
   "id":.....
   "name":

}
```

my question when i return workers should i have a field in the response "id" or "workerId"... what would be the best way?

Comment: There's no one answer to this. I've seen both. I would suggest you are consistent. If you use `workerId` then also use `buildingId`, or otherwise use `id` for both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be consistent.

No reals answer to this.

Answer (score 0):

Feel free about following the giant's practices as base, and you can extend whatever part you want. There is no strict answer, but be careful about the specifications like Open API.

For instance, Microsoft has a good documentation about the subject.

https://github.com/microsoft/api-guidelines/blob/vNext/azure/Guidelines.md